# intellij springboot typescript live update on webpage

Tags: intellij-idea, typescript, spring-boot

using angular2 with typescript and spring boot along with Intellij

when i make changes in my typescript file changes are not reflecting on to the web page but generated javascript file has my changes in. any help how to can configure live update ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my files were under resource folder, and what i found that resource folder is ignored for hot swap.

followed instructions on the following page and got it fixed

http://garywaddell.com/2015/11/20/spring-boot-intellij-idea-not-reloading-static-content/